# Is there a way to have the sort function return a 0 instead of NA when a value is not present?

Tags: r, sorting

I am using the ddply function to calculate bounded counts for a 3 pass snorkel survey. It works unless I have species that are only detected during one pass or only one pass was done at a site. How do I get the "second" in my ddply function to return a 0 value instead NA when a second highest value is not available, so the "bounded" calculation still works?

```
    Reach<-c("KW-2", rep("MER-1",7))
    Pass<-c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3)
    Species<-c("RBT","BRT","RBT","BRT","RBT", "Unk Trout", "BRT", "RBT")
    Count<-c(4,3,26,1,41,1,2,46)
    x<-data.frame(Reach, Pass, Species, Count)

    x
    Reach Pass   Species Count
    1  KW-2    1       RBT     4
    2 MER-1    1       BRT     3
    3 MER-1    1       RBT    26
    4 MER-1    2       BRT     1
    5 MER-1    2       RBT    41
    6 MER-1    2 Unk Trout     1
    7 MER-1    3       BRT     2
    8 MER-1    3       RBT    46

    x_BC_reach<-ddply(x, .(Reach, Species), summarize,
                       first = sort(Count,TRUE)[1],
                       second = sort(Count, TRUE)[2],
                       bounded = ((2*first)-second)/2)

    x_BC_reach
    Reach   Species first second bounded
    1  KW-2       RBT     4     NA      NA
    2 MER-1       BRT     3      2     2.0
    3 MER-1       RBT    46     41    25.5
    4 MER-1 Unk Trout     1     NA      NA
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use [`tidyverse`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tidyverse) syntax to tackle all data manipulation tasks. Let's say `df` is your data frame, you can do:

```
df <- df %>% 
    group_by(Reach, Species) %>% 
    summarise(first=sort(Count, TRUE)[1],
           second = sort(Count, TRUE)[2],
           bounded = ((2*first)-second)/2) %>% 
    replace_n(list(second=0)

    Reach   Species first second bounded
1  KW-2       RBT     4      0     0.0
2 MER-1       BRT     3      2     2.0
3 MER-1       RBT    46     41    25.5
4 MER-1 Unk Trout     1      0     0.0
```

Comment: This replaces the NA's in "bounded" to 0's as well. I would like to have only the NA's in "second" to be 0 so that the bounded eqn works. For example KW-2 would be ((2*4)-0)/2 = 4. The idea is that the value populated in "bounded" would be the same as the value in the "first" if a value didn't exist (0, or NA) in "second".

Comment: @Adockham Change the last line in the code to `replace_na(list(second=0))`

Answer (score 0):

It's actually not a problem with the `sort`, but with subsetting the result.

When you run `second = sort(Count, TRUE)[2]`, the `sort` returns `4` for the KW-2 case.
And `4[2]` returns `NA`, as there is no second element. So the easiest in this case would be telling R it needs to append with zero(es):

```
second = c(sort(Count, TRUE), 0)[2]
```